# How can I invoke an object dynamically in Perl Moose OOP?

Tags: perl, moose

Here is classical object model:

```
 class ViewBase
 {
  void DoSomethingForView() { } //May be virtual
 }

 class View1 : ViewBase //(derived class from ViewBase)
 {
    void DoSomethingForView() { }
    void DoSomethingForView1Special() { }
 }

 class View2: ViewBase //(another derived class from ViewBase)
 {
    void DoSomethingForView2Special() { }
 }

 class Application
 {
    void Print() { }
    void DoSomething() { }

     //Do some magic to create a view object (View1 or View2) and return

    //Something which I don't know to describe. Its like dynamically 
    //returning object of View1 or View2 at runtime
  }
```

I want to convert this to Perl Moose class model.

So that,

I will call the view methods like

```
void Main()
{

  App = new Application();

  App->View1->DoSomethingForView(); 
  App->View1->DoSomethingForView1Special();
  App->View2->DoSomethingForView(); 
  App->View2->DoSomethingForView2Special();
```

}

I will not know which View to be called. But at runtime, View1/View2 instance must be created & DoSomethingForView() must be called.

The above code is not exactly Perl. How to translate & achieve this in Perl.

An Application object shall have View object, but we will not know the type of the view at compile time. We have a test application, development in Perl.

You can imagine Application is a GUI application, and View is what you are seeing in the application window. User can select any view.

I am sorry about my English. Please let me know If I need to provide more text.

Comment: I think your calling example is a little wack. What's up with the "->void ..."

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here. Can you explain it more completely (not in code, just in prose)?

Comment: I'm still not understanding. You might get a better response on IRC (irc.perl.org/#moose) or the email list (moose@perl.org, probably requires subscribing first).

Comment: I think replacing the 'do some magic' and "Something I don't know how to describe" comments with actual implementations in, say, Java would be useful. We perl folk might not like programming in Java, but it's close enough to a lingua franca that we might be able to work out what you're after. Yes, I know this is the opposite of what Dave asked for, but it might still help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this gives you roughly equivalent syntax in Perl. It doesn't help you out with some of your conflicting criteria, though.

Note the following:

- class ABC {...} is replaced by the perl syntax package ABC;
- The capital camel-case method names are turned into proper "snake-case" perl.
- App has been turned to sigil-ed $App

This has been tested against Moose v62, Perl 5.10. Second from the last line will fail, because `do_something_for_view` is not implemented by `View2` class. As you're calling `view1` or `view2` specifically, I don't see the application for what you seem to indicate is polymorphism.

```
package ViewBase;

sub do_something_for_view { 
    Carp::croak "ViewBase::do_something_for_view is ABSTRACT!"; 
}

package View1;
use Moose;
extends 'ViewBase';

sub do_something_for_view { print "Doing something for View1.\n"; }
sub do_something_for_view1_special { print "Doing something SPECIAL for View1.\n"; }

package View2;
use Moose;
extends 'ViewBase';

sub do_something_for_view2_special() { print "Doing something SPECIAL for View2.\n"; }

package Application;
use Moose;

has view1 => ( 
      is      => 'rw'       # read/write
    , isa     => 'View1'
    , lazy    => 1
    , default => sub { View1->new(); } 
    );

has view2 => ( 
      is      => 'rw'       # read/write
    , isa     => 'View2'
    , lazy    => 1
    , default => sub { View2->new(); } 
    );

sub print {}
sub do_something {}

#void Main()
#{

package main;

  #App = new Application();
my $App = Application->new();

  #App->View1->DoSomethingForView(); 
$App->view1->do_something_for_view();
  #App->View1->DoSomethingForView1Special();
$App->view1->do_something_for_view1_special();
  #App->View2->DoSomethingForView(); 
$App->view2->do_something_for_view();
  #App->View2->DoSomethingForView2Special();
$App->view2->do_something_for_view2_special();

#}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [MooseX::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Declare) you might be able to simplify the syntax to something quite like what you first wrote, for instance, your declarations would turn into:

```
use MooseX::Declare;
 class ViewBase {
  method DoSomethingForView() { } #May be virtual
 }

 class View1 extends ViewBase {
    method DoSomethingForView() { }
    method DoSomethingForView1Special() { }
 }

 class View2 extends ViewBase {
    method DoSomethingForView2Special() { }
 }

 class Application {
    method Print() { }
    method DoSomething() { }

     #Do some magic to create a view object (View1 or View2) and return

    #Something which I don't know to describe. Its like dynamically 
    #returning object of View1 or View2 at runtime
  }
```